# EMMA failed to dump coverage data: java.io.FileNotFoundException: coverage.ec (Permission denied)

Tags: java, tomcat, code-coverage, emma

I have done the following steps.

1. Copied emma.jar into classpath
2. Instrumented the code and got coverage.em
3. Restarted server and checked the tomcat log(No suggestion of Emma collecting coverage data)
4. Started doing some tests on the application
5. Stopped tomcat, I get the below when I stopped tomcat.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: coverage.ec (Permission denied)
       at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
       at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:236)
       at com.vladium.emma.data.DataFactory.persist(DataFactory.java:656)
       at com.vladium.emma.data.DataFactory.persist(DataFactory.java:86)
       at com.vladium.emma.rt.RTCoverageDataPersister.dumpCoverageData(RTCoverageDataPersister.java:54)
       at com.vladium.emma.rt.RTExitHook.run(RTExitHook.java:32)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
 Exception in thread "EMMA shutdown handler thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: EMMA failed to dump coverage data: java.io.FileNotFoundException: coverage.ec (Permission de
       at com.vladium.emma.rt.RTCoverageDataPersister.dumpCoverageData(RTCoverageDataPersister.java:71)
       at com.vladium.emma.rt.RTExitHook.run(RTExitHook
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

Does Anyone know what step I am missing. I would greatly appreciate if anyone could help out.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This error:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: coverage.ec (Permission denied)`

Generally means that you don't have permission to read the file.  Verify that the user that is running the application has permissions to read coverage.ec, and that the file exists.

Comment: the coverage.ec file was never created, when I instrumented the code I only got the coverage.em file. How does Emma create the coverage.ec file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Win7, you may want to check whether your workspace is under "C:\". This caused a permissions issue for me. I changed my workspace into "C:\Users\[MyAccount]" and the permission issue was gone.